# The term 'jss' is not recognized while installing JSS

Tags: jss

I'm trying to install JSS on a VM.  When I run the install code, I get the following warnings:

```
PS C:\dev> npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
C:\Users\sitecore\AppData\Roaming\npm\jss -> C:\Users\sitecore\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\dist\bin\jss.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@9.0.6
updated 1 package in 8.154s`
```

Afterwards, when I try to test the installation, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\dev> jss --help
jss : The term 'jss' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ jss --help
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jss:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I can see that the files have installed at the location listed, but my machine never recognizes JSS commands.  I tried installing locally in the dev folder as well, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple things to try:

1. After global install, close/open your console. Sometimes console instances will cache path info.
2. Ensure that your `PATH` environment variable has your global npm cache folder listed.

Comment: #2 was the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: #2 worked. I have added it to system variables instead of user variables.

Answer (score 3):

- Ensure you have installed JSS module using `- npm install -g
  @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`
- If it is already done, make sure the npm path is correctly set in
  `Environment variables`. Also, try restarting the CMD prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find Jan Bluemink's answer that solved my issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626472/jss-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

- Check your environment path variable. Default the npm location on Windows is `C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- There you found a jss.cmd and the `node_modules\@sitecore-jss folder`
- To fix the "jss" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error add the npm location to your path or shortly `%AppData%\npm`
- To add somethings to the path go to control panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings then environment variables.

If you cant found the npm location try

```
npm config get prefix
```