# Error while installing Sitecore JSS CLI

Tags: jss

I have installed `Sitecore 10.2` on my pc and installed this `Sitecore Headless Services Server XP 19.0.0 rev. 00508.zip` for `Sitecore JSS`.

I have installed the latest version of a node using this file `node-v17.4.0-x64.msi`.

Now I'm just creating one POC where I need to consume Sitecore JSON data on react app.

I'm following below Url for that.

https://www.addact.net/create-sitecore-jss-react-application-and-apply-personalization

While executing the command `npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli` I'm getting the below error

```
41 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@sitecore-jss%2fsitecore-jss-cli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.25.35:443
41 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:110:14)
41 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
41 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
41 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:532:35)
41 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
41 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
41 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
42 verbose cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
43 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
44 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli"
45 verbose node v17.4.0
46 verbose npm  v8.3.1
47 error code ETIMEDOUT
48 error syscall connect
49 error errno ETIMEDOUT
50 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@sitecore-jss%2fsitecore-jss-cli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.25.35:443
51 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
51 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
51 error network
51 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
51 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
52 verbose exit 1
```

could anyone please help me to fix this issue? it is a blocker for me.

when I try to create react app using `jss create demojss react` then also getting below error.

```
jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: Did you see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626472/jss-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/the-term-jss-is-not-recognized-while-installing-jss/13319

Comment: please check wheatear you are in right dir

Comment: usually we get these errors when your vpn or firewall tries to block. Try after disconnecting your vpn.

Comment: Sitecore JSS is open source. You may raise ticket on Github https://github.com/sitecore/jss

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. After global install, close/open your console. Sometimes console instances will cache path info.

   - npm install -g
     @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
2. Ensure that your `PATH` `Environment variables` has your global npm cache folder listed.